# How can I mock a Macro attribute in Rust

Tags: rust

How can I mock a [macro attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#attribute-macros) when testing in Rust, is there some library to facilitate this?

For instance `#[my_macro]` modifies a struct applying  another macro `#[account()]` to one of his fields, this macro doesn't exist in my library but exists in the programs which are using my macro:

```
// lib.rs
extern crate proc_macro;
use proc_macro::TokenStream;

mod macros;

#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn my_macro(args: TokenStream, input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
      proc_macro::TokenStream::from(quote!(
          pub struct MyModifiedStruct{
            #[account()]
            pub field1: u8
          }
      ))
}
```

Now how can I test my_macro without getting an error for not having the `#[account()]` dependency in my library?

```
// tests/my_test.rs

#[test]
fn test_my_macro() {
    #[my_macro]
    pub struct MyStruct{}

    let my_struct = MyStruct{field1:1} 
    assert_eq!(my_struct.field1, 1)

}
```

My normal approach in Python would be mocking the `#[account()]` attribute, but not sure how can that be done in Rust.

Comment: Forgive me, but I'm really having trouble understanding what mocking an attribute would accomplish. If you're testing the macro then mocking it isn't testing anything, and if you're testing `foo` and want it unchanged just remove the attribute. Can you provide a less synthetic test that reflects the practical problem?

Comment: Maybe my example was just too basic, my particular problem is that I have a macro which returns rust code including some other attribute macro which does not exist in my macro library (but exist on the programs using my macro), thats the macro which I want to mock so it can basically be ignored when running tests. Otherwise will panic for the missing dependency.

Comment: Ah, thanks for explaining. There's no way AFIAK to supplant the behavior of a macro, but there may be some options like maybe an import trick or `cfg_attr(not(test), ...)` or you may just have to make your macro configurable so it doesn't emit the attribute. It's hard to know what will work without a more concrete example though.

Comment: Thanks @kmdreko that was already helpful. I have updated the example just in case you can think of a better way to accomplish this, but I think your suggestion `cfg_attr(not(test), ...)` already solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> My normal approach in Python would be mocking the `#[account()]` attribute, but not sure how can that be done in Rust.

You could implement a mock version of your `#[account]` attribute macro in the same proc-macro crate as `#[my_macro]` is defined and import it into the scope you are using `#[my_macro]` in:

**lib.rs:**

```rust
extern crate proc_macro;
use proc_macro::TokenStream;

mod macros;

#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn my_macro(args: TokenStream, input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
      proc_macro::TokenStream::from(quote!(
          pub struct MyModifiedStruct{
            #[account()]
            pub field1: u8
          }
      ))
}

#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn account(_args: TokenStream, input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    input
}
```

**tests/my_test.rs:**

```rust
// tests/my_test.rs
use your_crate::{my_macro, account};

#[test]
fn test_my_macro() {
    #[my_macro]
    pub struct MyStruct{}

    let my_struct = MyStruct{field1:1} 
    assert_eq!(my_struct.field1, 1)

}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas, already thought on this solution, but polluting my library just for passing tests didn't seem like the right approach. I would rather follow the `cfg_attr(not(test), ...)` approach suggested by @kmdreko.